# Readin information in reddit with urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I got the following code:

```
import urllib
import re

def worldnews():
    count = 0
    html = urllib.urlopen("https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/").readlines()

    lines = html
    for line in lines:
        if "Paris" or "Putin" in line:
            count = count + 1
            print line       

    print "Totaal gevonden: ", count
    print "----------------------"

worldnews()
```

How can I find all reddit post on that page with Paris or Puttin in the title. And Is there a way to print this title of the post to the console? When I run this now I get a lot of html code back.

Comment: Take a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: just a note, the line `if "Paris" or "Putin" in line:` will always return True, thats why you get a lot of HTML code. as said above, use BeautifulSoup or another HTML parsing lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to work with HTML in Python is [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).  So, you'll need to download that and look through the documentation to find out how to do exactly what you're asking.  However, I got you off to a start:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def worldnews():
    count = 0
    html = urllib.urlopen("https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    titles = soup.find_all('p',{'class':'title'})
    for i in titles:
        print(i.text)

worldnews()
```

When this is run, it gives an output that looks like this:

```
Paris attacks ringleader dead - French officials (bbc.com)
Company which raised price of AIDS drug by 5500% reports $14m quarterly losses. (pinknews.co.uk)
Syria/IraqSyrian man kills judge at ISIS Sharia Court for beheading his brother (en.abna24.com)
Putin Puts $50 Million Bounty on Heads of Metrojet Bombers (fortune.com)
```

and so on for all the titles on the page.  From here you should be able to figure out somewhat easily how to code the rest. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will help me

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you need help from there!

Comment: What is the best way to search in the results I get back from your script?  Because when I search on the titles I dont find anything. I think that I have to search the "href" but how :( Sorry I am new to Python

Comment: You could try adding them all to a list, then searching the lists for "Paris" or "Putin."